# one large table vs many small tables?

Tags: mysql

I'm a database newbie trying to migrate lots of our log files into MySQL database.

I put 4 month of data, 200 million rows in one MySQL table, using a timestamp column as Index. This design works fine when query covers shorter time range like 1 day. However when I do 2 month query EXPLAIN gives plan of a full table scan. Unfortunately, this long time range query happens quiet often.

I am thinking is it worth to divide this large table into 4 smaller tables? Will it helps in performance?

Comment: Since you are accessing roughly half of the rows in your table, a table scan may be the best choice

Comment: Agree. That seems to be what MySQL documentation tells, [You are using a key with low cardinality (many rows match the key value) through another column. In this case, MySQL assumes that by using the key it probably will do many key lookups and that a table scan would be faster.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-scan-avoidance.html)

Comment: What do you do with that amount of rows, aggregate or return them to the applikation?

Comment: They have been aggregated. I have a data mining application needs to pulling data from this data set often, based on different time range. Before I used a piece of code to process log files directly, since these log files coming from multiple sources that piece of code is very complex and hard to maintain. I'm hoping MySQL can do the same job using simpler query command.

Comment: Not sure I understand, perhaps you should reveal the query you are using?

Comment: Have you considered using any of the specialised log analysis tools out there - some of them Open Source? You might want to poke around [this site](http://www.chuvakin.org/) - this guy is Mr. Logging!

Comment: You should partition your tables. If MySQL can't do it, then use Postgres instead.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1519917711  AND 152268251; That's all I do.

Comment: Thanks Colin! I think partition is the right path to solve it. I'm looking at it now. And MySQL support partitioning.

Comment: Pulling 100 miljon rows back to the application will be a challenge. If they dont reside in memory, you will need a good disksystem to handle the i/o

Comment: I think the possible way is to partition Your table by primary timestamp field, monthly, for example. Study https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html . In practice while using `WHERE partitioning_key BETWEEN lowest AND highest` only partitions contained values needed are scanned. But this method decreases cardinality of primary index for one (primarely the last) partition - it may alter the query plans from index scan to table scan when filter is thin.

Comment: What will you be doing with the 100M rows?  Perhaps summarizing the data in a way that could be done in SQL?  See  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint and http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables